# D6: Create a new template for a specific url of node type page

Tags: 6, theming

I'm trying to create a completely different template for a page I have set up at:

http://www.example.com/my_page

I thought I just added a new node tpl page (node-my_page.tpl.php), but that doesn't appear to be working. What's the trick?

Comment: You can use a template like `node-[nid].tpl.php`, where `[nid]` is the node id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-my_page.tpl.php` wont work without additional code. `page-my_page.tpl.php` will in case `my_page` is the system path (node and page templates are not the same thing though). If it's an alias you should find out the system path and create the template file using that. For example if the system path is `node/5` you'd create `page-node-5.tpl.php`.

If simple template suggestions aren't quite enough you can use the code snippets I added below to make things work (copy to your theme template file).

Different page template:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'my_page') {
    $variables['template_file'] = 'page-my_page';
  }
}
```

Different node (content part of a page) template:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'my_page') {
    $variables['template_file'] = 'node-my_page';
  }
}
```

Note that if `my_page` is not the system path, but only the alias you should use the system path (`node/5` in this example) instead:

```
if ($_GET['q'] == 'node/5') {
  // ...
}
```

Or let Drupal get the alias for you:

```
$alias = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
if ($alias == 'my_page') {
  // ...
}
```

You can find more information and additional examples [here](http://drupal.org/node/223440).

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for are [template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642). If you want to change the page layout (regions, general html) use template suggestions for page.tpl.php. OTOH, if you want to change the node layout (the .node div and whatever is within), use template suggestion for node.tpl.php.

Comment: Yea, I saw that, but what if I want to change a template based on a URL? I don't see that mentioned anywhere.

Comment: page-[front|internal/path].tpl.php the internal/path is the url. Do you want to change the node layout or the page layout?

Comment: The node layout. It needs a completely different look. New css, new layout, everything.

Comment: try node-nid.tpl.php.